# How to eliminate database table row duplication

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, vb.net

I have a question on databases and how information is displayed in regards to Primary and Foreign keys.

For example, there are three tables; `Employees`, `Employee_tickets` and `Employee_comments`. 
Each `employee`can have multiple `tickets` and also multiple `comments`.  A foreign key is placed in the Employee tickets and Employee Comments table.  My application is built in vb.net with Visual Studio and it is a desktop application.  How can I query say.. Employee Name ('Jon Doe') and display all of his tickets in a grid as well as all of the comments people have made on him over time?  I have created a View on the sql database which returns all of the information I require but for each ticket listed under ('Jon Doe') the View displays and Employee Name for every single ticket.  Is there a way to display the employee name only once and then every ticket listed under that particular individual without displaying the Employee Name again or do I have to make Separate windows to segregate all of this?

This seems like a really dumb question and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to correctly display what is required in this situation.

Here is an example of what I am trying to explain:[image]

So for troy there is one employee name entered in the Employee Names table, There is one CWB ticket entered in the CWB table but there are TWO PQ Cards entered in the PQR Ticket table.   How Can I Display    only one row for Troy and one Row for his CWB because there are only one of each entered in the tables then the two rows for the PQR Cards under his name?

I have created a view which gathers this information all into the one single view itself then bound the datagridview's to this View.

Comment: You could comma delimit the results in the employee tickets and employee comments column so everything will should in one row rather than multiple.  Like this:    John Doe    2,3,4,5,6   Emp Comemnt,Emp Comment1,Emp Comment2,Emp Comment3

Comment: When the results are returned from the database the data for employee comments and employee tickets would be in one column and it would be comma  delimited so you would have one row returned  and all the results for Employee Comments and Employee Tickets would be in one row

Comment: How do you bind the view with the DataGrid?

Comment: I just used the dropdown on the Datagrid and selected the bindingsource to the view that I created. Then selected the columns do display in each grid just for an example to what I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with databases.  Rather, the issue is that you have an entity (the employee) that has two separate collections associated with it (tickets and comments) and you want to show the contents of both collections.

Doing this in a datagrid is difficult because in its simplest incarnation it's intended to show one collection of like items.

I can think of a number of possibilities:

1. In your code, convert each collection to a single string value and display that single string value on the row with the employee's name.  This conversion could be to comma-separate a stringified version of each item in the collection (as suggested by BS123 in the comments) or could simply be a summary (eg "5 Tickets").
2. Put the basic employee information in one data grid and then have two additional data grids below it, one bound to the Tickets collection and one to the Comments collection.
3. Embed data grids directly in the main data grid, one in the Tickets column and one in the Comments column, and bind each one to the appropriate collection in the employee.

Your database structure is correct so don't change that, you simply need to solve the issue of presentation.

Comment: I was just thinking maybe collect the information in separate views then bind each view to the datagrid's then it would display one row for the name and each ticket for that name, Would I just fun a filter on the binding source in the application to align the Primary and foreign keys for  each entry? How can I embed multiple datagrids into one?

Comment: Forget primary keys, foreign keys, or anything having to do with a database.  By the time you're presenting the information on the screen you have, presumably, constructed objects and collections of objects which are separate from the database.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing here is a controller between your view and your model. Your view is presenting exactly what it was given to present - it's up to you to format it.

There are several possible solutions to this, and the correct one partially depends on needs and infrastructure.

If you infrastructure is solid and your needs are near real time, consider dropping separately querying to fill your second and third tables based on what is picked in the first. This will increase the load on the database, but your data will almost always be correct, and the data will come from the database the way you want to see it.

If the database-centered solution is not good for you, LINQ provides some good ways to filter your data into typed collections that would present exactly what you want the user to see.

To get the users:

```
Dim users = From l In data.lines
            Group By FirstName = l.firstName, LastName = l.lastName
            Into Tickets = Group, Count()
```

You can then present this object to your grid. While dynamic typing works here, I think it would be easier to manage view interactions with defined classes. I'll leave that part up to you. Do some searching on LINQ to fill in the rest of the blanks. It's pretty neat stuff.